# error code during application install -24 on Rooted device from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to install the App from Google Play Store. Gets downloaded and fails during installation with:

```
        unknown error code during application install -24
```

The Same Application got installed with different certificate during debug runs from Android Studio. Now it is not getting deleted or over written. How can i clear the cache completely?

Connected the Mobile using USB and tried to run debug from Android Studio. I get following error on debug run APK transfer.

```
        Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the app through Terminal using adb shell command helped in one of the mobile.

In other mobile, even adb shell command did not work out.

Resetting mobile to Factory setting as final solution helped.

PS: Please voteup if you find this helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check manifest file and compare with previous one.

If your manifest file contain android:sharedUserId in previous version and it is absent in current version then this error will occured.

Solution is uninstall it and install fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of Google Play Store Error Unknown Error Code During Application Install: 24 is cache problem. However, it can arise at different aspects as listed below:

  It can be due to Google Play Store Cache and Data problem.

  It can arise due to unwanted junk and residue files.

  This error can also appear if you are trying to install an app which was earlier installed in your phone and was uninstalled but all the files of the app was not deleted from your phone.

  It can also be caused if your internal storage is full.

Depending on the causes, there are 5 Solutions to Fix Google Play Store Error Unknown Error Code During Application Install: 24. They are listed below:

**Solution 1** – Restart your Android Phone.
**Solution 2** – Clear Cache and Data of Google Play Store, Google Service Framework and Download Manager.
**Solution 3** – Remove Junk files from your internal storage.
**Solution 4** – Check if you have sufficient memory in your internal storage.
**Solution 5** – Factory Reset your Android Phone.